# Displaying information about an order when selection changes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, linq, entity-framework

I feel like just because the below works doesn't mean it is correct, I want to improve it but I can't really figure out how. Besides the fact it is down right ugly I feel the performance could be increased a lot also.

Am I even using the Entity Framework and/or LINQ the way it is supposed to be used?

So I have these classes:

```
[Table("OrderInfo")]
public class OrderInfo
{
    public long ID {get; set;}
    public long OrderID {get; set;}
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public long ItemID {get; set;}
    public double Qty { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}

[Table("Items")]
public class Item
{

    public Item()
    {
        this.Orders = new List<OrderInfo>();
    }
    #region Strings
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Column(@"Sheet/Roll")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryMachine { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Long
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long? Weight { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Doubles
    public double? Size1 { get; set; }
    public double? Size2 { get; set; }
    public double? Size3 { get; set; }
    #endregion.

    public virtual ICollection<OrderInfo> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

below is the code calling the data:

```
    private void dgvOrders_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dgvOrderItems.DataSource != null)
                dgvOrderItems.DataSource = null;

            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(dgv["ID", dgv.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value);
            List<OrderInfo> OrderInfo = new List<OrderInfo>();
            OrderInfo = c.OrderInfo.Include("Item").Where(x => x.OrderID == ID).ToList();

             if(OrderInfo.Count <= 0)
             {
                MessageBox.Show("No Info Found For This Order!");
                ClearForm();
                return;
             }

            lblPO.Text = "P.O. # " + OrderInfo[0].ID.ToString();
            lblRequestedBy.Text = "Requested By: " + OrderInfo[0].Order.RequestedBy;
            lblOrderDate.Text = "Ordered On: " + OrderInfo[0].Order.Date.ToShortDateString();

            dgvOrderItems.DataSource = OrderInfo.Select(x => new { x.ItemID, x.Qty, x.Item.FullName, x.Item.Brand, x.Item.Color }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/47890/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Architecture

One thing that jumps forward is that you're going straight from the UI to your datasource. In a three-layer design (UI, Model, Persistence) or MVC (Model, View, Controller) there is always a layer between the UI and your datasource.

A samplesetup would be this:

```
interface IOrderRepository {
    IEnumerable<OrderInfo> GetOrderById(int id);
}

class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository {
    public IEnumerable<OrderInfo> GetOrderById(int id){
        using(var context = new MyDataContext()){
            return context.OrderInfo.Include("Item").Where(x => x.OrderID == ID).ToList();
        }
    }
}

class UIController {
    private IOrderRepository _orderRepository;
    
    public void OnOrdersSelectionChanged(DataGridView view){
        _orderRepository.GetOrderById(Convert.ToInt32(dgv["ID", dgv.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value));
    }
}
```

Now your view is coupled loose from your datasource through the intermediate repository. You might be interested in reading up on the repository pattern, for example [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wriju/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework).

## Resources

I don't see a `using` statement in your code so I assume that your `DataContext` is held as a private field. This context class is explicitly made to be disposed after using it once so you should use it as such.

In the MSDN blog I linked just before the repository is disposed instead which is also an option although I have found that wrapping all calls to the `DataContext` is more often used.

## Braces

Always add your braces to your `if` statements, even when it's just one line. It's simply too easy to make mistakes.

## Inline declaration

This snippet

```
List<OrderInfo> OrderInfo = new List<OrderInfo>();
OrderInfo = c.OrderInfo.Include("Item").Where(x => x.OrderID == ID).ToList();
```

is an elaborate way of writing

```
var orderInfo = c.OrderInfo.Include("Item").Where(x => x.OrderID == ID).ToList();
```

Notice also how I made `orderInfo` lowercase. Keep naming conventions in mind!

Comment: Do you have any more links? I have been trying to implement the Repository system, and keepo having issues like from that link when I try to use the `IQueryable<Order> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Order, object>>[] includeProperties);` method I get an error `query = query.Include(includeProperty);` that Include is not part of Context.Order. Any additional links would be great

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.be/search?q=repository+pattern+entity+framework&oq=repository+pat&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0j69i61j0l2.4168j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) yields many results, all of them which look pretty good. If you need assistance with not-working code, don't forget to visit Stack Overflow!